# why folder structure is not created even though I had taken package statement?

Tags: java

I was trying a package concept in java.

I created a `Test.java` file that only contains a single statement:

```
package pack1;
```

When I compile the file using the command as:

```
javac -d . Test.java
```

it compiles fine but doesn't create the `.class` file, nor a folder named `pack1`.

I don't know why. Can anyone please suggest?

If I change the code to:

```
package pack1;
class Test{}
```

and compile the program by using the command

```
javac -d . Test.java
```

Then it compiles fine and folder structure is also created correctly.

Please suggest me why it happens that way?

Comment: The package declaration simply isn't enough to be compiled to some valid `.class` file...

Answer (score 3):

In your original code, you haven't declared any classes - so there *wouldn't* be any class files. If there are no class files, presumably the compiler sees no need to create the directory structure that *would* have been necessary for any class files it *would* have created.

In practice, the only time I've ever seen a Java source file with no classes in is for package information - and that's pretty pointless if there are no classes in the package, too, although it's possible that if you run javadoc it will create an entry for the empty package. As noted in comments, package *annotations* will end up creating a class file, but they have to be in `package-info.java`. For example:

```
// In package-info.java
@Deprecated
package foo;
```

Compiling that will create `package-info.class`, creating a directory for it if necessary.

Comment: You can compile "package-info.java" and javac will generate a .class file if you have some package level attributes in it.

Comment: @PeteKirkham: What sort of "attributes" do you mean here? It doesn't seem to happen for just Javadoc comments. Do you mean package annotations?

Comment: @PeteKirkham: Have edited the answer for annotations now.